# "MissingRegion" : could not find region configuration, but I have it in my ~/.aws.config

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

My code:

```
sess = session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    Profile: "gms-ai",
}))
```

My `~/.aws/config`:

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1

[profile gms-ai]
output = json
region = us-east-2
```

But for example this is working snipet from my deployment script:

```
AWS_PROFILE=gms-ai \
aws lambda update-function-code...
```

So looks like `aws cli` do read `region` but AWS SDK ignore it?

Comment: Is it when you run it locally that you get that error or when you run it in AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. See here:

> By default the SDK will only load the shared credentials file's (~/.aws/credentials) credentials values, and all other config is provided by the environment variables, SDK defaults, and user provided aws.Config values.
>
> If the AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG environment variable is set, or SharedConfigEnable option is used to create the Session the full shared config values will be loaded. This includes credentials, region, and support for assume role. In addition the Session will load its configuration from both the shared config file (~/.aws/config) and shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials). Both files have the same format.

Link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/#NewSessionWithOptions).

So just set the AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG environment variable to read the config.